# I have 4 radiobuttons in each row of Gridview. I am using onClick method on each Radiobutton, But now i want ot use that use using Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 4 radiobuttons in each row of Gridview. I am using the onClick method on each Radiobutton, but now I want to use Javascript / jQuery.
This is code which I am using in behind (aspx.cs) file. But I want to use it using javascript / Jquery.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            RadioButton rad1 = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton1");
            RadioButton rad2 = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton2");
            RadioButton rad3 = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton3");
            RadioButton rad4 = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton4");
            if (rad1.Checked == true)
            {
                rad2.Checked = false;
                rad3.Checked = false;
                rad4.Checked = false;
            } if (rad2.Checked == true)
            {
                rad1.Checked = false;
                rad3.Checked = false;
                rad4.Checked = false;
            } if (rad3.Checked == true)
            {
                rad1.Checked = false;
                rad2.Checked = false;
                rad4.Checked = false;
            } if (rad4.Checked == true)
            {
                rad1.Checked = false;
                rad2.Checked = false;
                rad3.Checked = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arun is correct about the naming thing, but If you want each radio button to be named something different then you can set the `checked` property to false this way.

```js
$(document).on('click','.radio-class',function(){
  $this = $(this);
  // uncheck all other radio inputs except this one
  $('.radio-class').not($this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="radio" class="radio-class" name="RadioButton1" id="rad1"  />
  <input type="radio" class="radio-class" name="RadioButton2" id="rad2"  />
  <input type="radio" class="radio-class" name="RadioButton3" id="rad3"  />
  <input type="radio" class="radio-class" name="RadioButton4" id="rad4"  />
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u so Much, Its Working after little Modification in radiobutton. `<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="radio-class" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you give same value for name property, then automatically only one among those radio buttons can be selected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Radio button demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="radio" name="commonName" id="rad1" onclick="alert('rad1 clicked !')" />
  <input type="radio" name="commonName" id="rad2" onclick="alert('rad2 clicked !')" />
  <input type="radio" name="commonName" id="rad3" onclick="alert('rad3 clicked !')" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want it for Gridview eah row one radiobutton selecction among four.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is in a GridView I would think you want something like the following.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RadioButtons">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radioButtonList">
                    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now you should not need any javascript/jquery or onclick code behind.

Comment: No No, I have to add 4 Radio buttons and to load different fields from db in each radio buttons.

Comment: Would you please add your designer code from the gridview.